# How to fetch table names from a particular postgres database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have created a table in database using controller so that on click of a button this create_table controller action invokes and i have not used model.

Now i want to fetch the table names from a particular database, should i create a model? or how to do it?

please help i am pretty new to rails, i searched a lot and then posted this question coz i didn't get satisfactory answers.

This is my controller action.

```
def create_table    

    require 'pg'

    begin

    con = PG.connect :dbname => 'testdb', :user => 'abcd', :host => 'xyz'

    con.exec "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars"
    con.exec "CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        Name VARCHAR(20), Price INT)"

    rescue PG::Error => e

    puts e.message 

    ensure

    con.close if con

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get table names from DB without ActiveRecord and models - use sql:

```
#for pg
tables = con.exec("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'").to_a
```

It returns a list of tables that you create.

Comment: i want to  pass tables from controller to view to show all table names in browser.  what to do ?

Comment: You can define variable with `@`, for example, `@tables` in controller action and it will be available in this action view as `@table`, to show - `<%= @tables %>`

Comment: you can read more about rails views in official guide - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to `rails` it is a good idea to work through some of the guides (e.g. starting with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html). This will give you a much better start than trying to manipulate the database by hand. One of the great advantages of rails (and one I most sorely miss when working outside of it) is the concept of database migrations (as outlined e.g. in [this article on `ActiveRecord`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)).

You will basically learn how to create tables as a consequence of creating models. You can create a new model by using a generator or as a beginner you might even chose to use the whole `scaffold` generator, e.g.

```
rails generate scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer
```

This will generate the `Model` class (derived from `ActiveRecord::Base`), the database migration to create the `HighScore` table, a `HighScoreController` object for manipulating it and a host of templates which produce a set of pages for your regular `CRUD` operations (that is `Create`, `Read`, `Update`, `Delete`).

It is not the usual `rails` way to create tables on the fly through some user action, but you create tables through a migration in the development environment. This will allow you to migrate it into production at the appropriate time. A much better way to interact with the structure of a (live) database than through a hacky bit of of DDL-SQL I assure you.

Comment: You're welcome. The most accepted form of saying "thank you" on stackoverflow is to accept an answer. (No worries, you can always change your mind later if something better turns up.)

Comment: i am using the method above because i want to create a table everytime on a click of a button and its getting created in DB , but now i want to know whether i can create a model and fetch the table names ? @Patru

Comment: There *may* be a reason to drop the table and recreate it at the press of the button, but it is not obvious from the code you have provided. Usually you want to create a **row** in a table in order to *still* have it next time somebody comes around. Dropping the table at every click will most probably eradicate the usefulness of your site immediately, therefore `rails` does not cater well for your use case. Please explain your reasoning if you expect any *good* answers.